# issue while verifying domain name in cloud identity

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am not able to verifying the domain name in cloud identity. My domain name is with  other provider and the cloud identity is looking for domain name on godaddy.com. any idea what can I do excepting migrating the domain to godaddy.com ?

[image]

What I found is that google is automatically trying to detect the Registrar of the domain name. See highlighted text below:

[image]

my domain is on ewebguru.com. See the updated picture added above , the text says "We've detected that your domain host is GoDaddy.com. Click below to sign in to verify ownership." So, anyone from google can comment on what to do in this situation?

Comment: 1. Please clear that you want to transfer a domain from Google to Godaddy or from Godaddy to Google. 2. You just want to verify your domain in cloud identity ?

Comment: my domain name is with other provider and it looks like now google only support domains from godaddy. I was thinking if I can use my domain name without moving the domain name to godaddy.com.

Comment: Could you please provide a domain provider name so, that I will share troubleshooting steps. Google will support all providers not just Godaddy.

Comment: The provider is ewebguru.com.

Comment: in every step of verification it is showing godaddy.com and I didnt find the option to change it to ewebguru.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

protecting domain name with TXT worked. Though it was showing godaddy.com as a registrar it was able to pick my domain from ewebguru.com.

issue resolved.

Thanks to all who tried to help me resolving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please do Cloud Identity Signup from this [page](https://workspace.google.com/gcpidentity/signup/welcome?sku=identitybasic#0) as you already have a domain from another provider.

For the verification you need to have DNS records and check this [link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/183895#generic_TXT) when your domain register is not in the list and check this [video](https://youtu.be/QL5oIWBrhP0) as well.
Once you complete the above process; you can complete [verification](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/7331243). By adding verification code and telling Google to verify your code.

If still your issue is not resolved; we have a chat through stack chats.

Comment: I have done this in the past about 2 year back and I understand how it works. I have seen your given links and understand them. but in my case I am not able to use my registrar. let me know your availability and how to use stack chat.

Comment: Mon or Tue 2PM IST would be fine for u?

Comment: give me some time I will provide you the meeting time.

Comment: See the updated picture added above , the text says "We've detected that your domain host is GoDaddy.com. Click below to sign in to verify ownership." So, anyone from google can comment on what to do in this situation?